# Build related Dataframes in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a `df_player` with data from a player 'John' that has played for 5 teams along his carrear:

```
teams = ['Liverpool', 'Chelsea', 'City', 'United', 'Burnley']
```

Now I want to test his performance in pairs, his next team against his former team, like so:

```
Chelsea X Liverpool
City X Chelsea
United X City
Burnley X United
```

I'm trying to do this in a loop using `pandas`. Dataframe has columns like this:

```
...
name           280502 non-null object
team_name      280502 non-null object
adversary_name 280502 non-null object
....
```

So far I have:

```
for team in teams:
    df_former_team = df_player[(df_player['name'] == 'John')
                               &(df_player['team_name'] == team] 

    df_next_team = df_former_team[df_former_team['adversary_name'].isin(teams)
```

---

But I need the analysis to be made in pairs, like the example above, in (next, former) fashion.

How do I do it with `pandas`?

EDIT:

A solution provided below:

```
for team, next_team in zip(teams, teams[1:]):
    print (team, next_team)
```

prints:

```
Liverpool Chelsea
Chelsea City
City United
United Burnley
```

but the correct answer should print the other way around:

```
Chelsea Liverpool 
City Chelsea 
United City
Burnley United
```

There is no need for a dataframe output, this above the expect output. Then dataframes will be filtered correctly.

Comment: kindly share a sample dataframe with expected output. Easier to work this way

Comment: Is it really needed? I think the issue in how to slice the list. The question is about the expected INPUT in the condition, not the output

Comment: Sample data is really needed if you want us to understand exactly what you want to do. Have you tried `for team, next_team in zip(teams, teams[1:]):` ?

Comment: Or `df.groupby(['team_name', 'adversary_name'])`

Comment: @RichieV please refer to my edit. you are almost there

Comment: You should really prefer the groupby, even if you only use a few groups, aggregating a groupby object is a lot more efficient than manually filtering on each iteration. Regarding the order, you can just swap the list passed to groupby.

Comment: Care to answer?

Answer (score 0):

This will return the output of games in which `John` plays against one of his former teams.
Is this what you want?

```
player_games = df_player.query('name == "John"')
pair_performance = player_games.query('team_name in @teams or adversary_name in @teams')
```

Comment: This helps. But what I really need, from a list of `[n, n+1, n+2, n+3, n+4...]`, is to build dataframes  in pairs `(n, n+1)`,`(n+2, n+3)`, and so on, in the loop, or else.

Comment: Are the dataframes sorted by order of the team he was on?
Look up pd.DataFrame.shift(1), this will shift all the rows down by one. `pair_performance['former_team'] = df_player['adversary_team'].shift(-1)`

Comment: Can you please add more examples? I think your current implementation will fail if the player goes back to their old team.

Comment: Yes it is sorted chronologically. Precisely like the list, which was obtained from team unique values, sorted in that order